# Does this code contain use-after-free?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
int f2(char* x, int f) {
    int i=0;
    free(x);
    if(f) {
        printf("%s", x); 
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char argv) {
    char* x = malloc(10);
    return f2(x, argc);
}
```

Is passing freed pointer to printf considered use-after free?

Comment: free prior to use ... bruh

Comment: @Stargateur Reference?

Comment: f2 is not defined and if its not a typo, there you have your first error. if f1 is called then, yes it is "use after free".

Comment: @Stargateur Oh, wait. it's not a value here. It is used as a pointer. Didn't notice the format specifier. But if it was `%p` I don't think it would be UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, it takes me time to find where I read it, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior/2775/read-value-of-pointer-that-was-freed#t=201706071444349704681.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks. That's a really counter-intuitive point. Just another nitpick - "indeterminate" is not undefined. BTW, found an interesting doc about indeterminate values stability: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1793.pdf

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo, I have fixed it already.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "*... don't think it would be UB.*" It would: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior/2775/read-value-of-pointer-that-was-freed#t=201706071809120620508

Comment: @alk See the above comment about indeterminate VS undefined...

Answer (score 1):

You'll get *undefined behaviour* (google that term) several times:

1. in `f2` you are dereferencing `x` once it has been freed, because `printf`ing `x` with the `%s` format specifier will dereference `x`, or in other words it will access the memory pointed by `x`, and that memory will have undetermined content after calling `free`.
2. even if you remove the `free(x`), you still get undefined behaviour, because then you are `printf`ing `x`, while `x` is pointing to valid but non initialized memory.