# Behaviour on setting a pointer to a dangling pointer

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I've come across some assertions that the behaviour on setting a pointer to something that isn't the address of a scalar or one past the address of a scalar is undefined (with similar restrictions for arrays).

So consider this:

```
int main()
{
    int* bar;
    {
        int foo = 1;
        int* b = &foo;
        bar = b;
    }     
    int* copy = bar;    
}
```

Is the behaviour of `int* copy = bar;` defined? `bar` no longer points to a scalar as it's out of scope.

Comment: *dereferencing* it would definitely be undefined, but I'm not entirely sure about this. It's unproblematic in practice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `bar` is indeterminate after the close bracket.

Quoting ISO/IEC 9899:2011, section 6.2.4 §2:

> […] The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

The exact behavior of `int* copy = bar;` is ambiguous — see [N1793 — Stability of indeterminate values in C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1793.pdf) provided by [eugene-sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415381/does-this-code-contain-use-after-free?noredirect=1#comment75830978_44415381).

Comment: Wow. So that means I shouldn't really take the copy.

Comment: @PaulLogue What is the point anyway (add it to your question if you want answer to this) ? But yes, this is not very safe.